# postgresql view add column with constraint

Tags: postgresql

I tried to add a column in a view.
Just that... Ok with Create OR REPLACE. But the calculus is only possible if a other column is not 0 (or Null).
My request:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW schema.table AS 
SELECT n.id,n.db_lo,n.db_hi,n.pop_2012,n.tot_area,n.geom,n.area,n.pop,10*log((10^((db_lo+2.5)/10))*n.pop) 
FROM schema.table as n 
where n.pop!=0
```

id, db_lo,db_hi pop_2012,tot_area, geom, area and pop are already in my view.

Can you help me?

Thx.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Next that request, my view is broke. When I want to see my data's I receive ERROR: infinite recursion detected in rules for relation "view". It's schema.view not schema.table

Comment: Why are you creating a view that has the same name as the table? Does that even run?

Comment: The table doesn't exist any more, it's a previous try.

Comment: I'm referring to: `VIEW schema.table` vs. `FROM schema.table`  - obfuscating your table and view names isn't really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try using `n.db_lo` instead of `db_lo`.